How to divide elements of a single DataFrame column into multiple
I'm trying to split a DataFrame column score into multiple different columns but am having issues because it is telling me that if let scoreColumn = gameTrainingData["score"] as? Column<Dictionary<String, Optional<Any>>>   will always fail even though it is the type of the column. I've checked the documentation to see if there was built in function to do this but it didn't seem so.
Here is what I currently have:
// Extract relevant information from the 'score' column
        if let scoreColumn = gameTrainingData["score"] as? Column<Dictionary<String, Optional<Any>>>  {
            let winnerColumn = scoreColumn.map { ($0!["winner"] as? String) ?? "UNKNOWN" }
            let fullTimeHomeColumn = scoreColumn.map { ($0!["fullTime"] as? [String: Int])?["home"] ?? -1 }
            let fullTimeAwayColumn = scoreColumn.map { ($0!["fullTime"] as? [String: Int])?["away"] ?? -1 }
            
            // Add these as new columns to the DataFrame
            gameTrainingData.append(column: Column(name: "winner", contents: winnerColumn))
            gameTrainingData.append(column: Column(name: "fullTimeHome", contents: fullTimeHomeColumn))
            gameTrainingData.append(column: Column(name: "fullTimeAway", contents: fullTimeAwayColumn))
        }
        
        // Define feature columns based on the extracted data
        let featureColumns = [
            "homeTeam",
            "awayTeam",
            "fullTimeHome",
            "fullTimeAway",
            "referees"
        ]
        
        // Model Setup
        let parameters = MLRandomForestClassifier.ModelParameters(
            validation: .split(strategy: .automatic),
            maxIterations: 100,
            randomSeed: 38
        )
        
        let model = try MLRandomForestClassifier(
            trainingData: gameTrainingData,
            targetColumn: "winner", // Assuming you're predicting the winner
            featureColumns: featureColumns,
            parameters: parameters
        )

If someone could provide some feedback about how to properly create new columns from elements of a single column for model training it would be much appreciated.
Edit
Example Input:
"score": {
    duration = REGULAR;
    fullTime =     {
        away = 0;
        home = 2;
    };
    halfTime =     {
        away = 0;
        home = 0;
    };
    winner = "HOME_TEAM";
}

This is gets turned into the score column:
, ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ score                                              ┃
┃ <Dictionary<String, Optional<Any>>>                ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 0;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 2;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 1;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 1;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 0;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 1;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 1;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 1;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 1;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 1;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 0;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 1;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 0;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 2;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 0;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 1;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 2;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 0;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 1;
    home = … │
│ ["halfTime": Optional({
    away = 1;
    home = … │
┢╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍┪
┇ 23 more                                            ┇
┗╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍╍┛

Which I would like to split into  fullTimeHome and  fullTimeAway to use to train my model to predict the final score of matches.

Can you show an example input and the desired output?

@Sweeper I've added input, I don't have any examples out desired output, but have described it.

Okay, I understand your problem now. Where did gameTrainingData come from? It seems like you are putting JSON data directly into a dataframe. I would parse the JSON data into a more convenient format first - a Codable struct for example - instead of working with [String: Any?]s.
